# multiple json objects in in object (json.net)

Tags: json.net

Is it possible to get an format like this :

```
"list":{
  "one":{
    "fieldone":"-----",
    "fieldtwo":"-----"
   },
  "two":{
     "fieldone":"-----",
     "fieldtwo":"-----"
   }
 }
```

I don't want an array [] or the names "one" and "two" to be removes, I am struggling to get the exact following format.

Comment: Is the problem encoding, decoding or displaying the data?

Comment: I am having data, and I want so serialize them into this format, but I cannot see how to add multiple json objects in on json object, when I am using a list object, the "list" becomes an array instead of a json object and the fields "on" and "two" just disapear.

Comment: Use Custom `JsonConverter`. http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you put your items into a dictionary instead of a list then you can get the result you want.  Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RootObject obj = new RootObject();
        obj.Items = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
        obj.Items.Add("one", new Item { FieldOne = "foo", FieldTwo = "bar" });
        obj.Items.Add("two", new Item { FieldOne = "fizz", FieldTwo = "bang" });

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("list")]
    public Dictionary<string, Item> Items { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("fieldone")]
    public string FieldOne { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("fieldtwo")]
    public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "list": {
    "one": {
      "fieldone": "foo",
      "fieldtwo": "bar"
    },
    "two": {
      "fieldone": "fizz",
      "fieldtwo": "bang"
    }
  }
}
```